# How does OpportunityPartner gets created?

Tags: opportunity, partner-communities, partner-portal

To some opportunites, opportunitypartner is getting created and for some it is not getting created.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitypartner.htm
According to above link it is said it will create automatically.

please help

Comment: OpportunityPartner records are created only when there is a relationship established between a Partner (Account) record and an Opportunity. Does your flow suffice this condition? Refer to this from the docs: *When you create a partner relationship between an account and an opportunity (when you create a Partner record **and specify the OpportunityId field**), the API automatically creates an OpportunityPartner record*